# Vercel Deployment error: Build Failed Command "npm install" exited with 1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json, vercel

I used create-react-app. Project runs fine locally, but when I try to deploy through Vercel, it throws these errors:

```
[19:04:02.390] Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
[19:04:03.523] Cloning completed: 1.141s
[19:04:03.866] Running "vercel build"
[19:04:04.353] Vercel CLI 32.1.0
[19:04:04.915] Installing dependencies...
[19:04:06.771] npm notice 
[19:04:06.771] npm notice New major version of npm available! 9.5.1 -> 10.0.0
[19:04:06.772] npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.0.0>
[19:04:06.772] npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.0.0` to update!
[19:04:06.772] npm notice 
[19:04:06.773] npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR! 
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR! While resolving: @testing-library/react@13.4.0
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR! node_modules/react
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.11.1
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.11.1" from the root project
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.11.0
[19:04:06.776] npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.11.0" from the root project
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR!       3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR!     3 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system)
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR!   22 more (@emotion/styled, ...)
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR! 
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR! peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR! 
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR! node_modules/react
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
[19:04:06.777] npm ERR! 
[19:04:06.778] npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
[19:04:06.778] npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
[19:04:06.778] npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
[19:04:06.778] npm ERR! 
[19:04:06.778] npm ERR! 
[19:04:06.778] npm ERR! For a full report see:
[19:04:06.778] npm ERR! /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-09-02T11_04_05_260Z-eresolve-report.txt
[19:04:06.779] 
[19:04:06.779] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[19:04:06.779] npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-09-02T11_04_05_260Z-debug-0.log
[19:04:06.796] Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

Already tried upgrading and downgrading react, but ended with similar result- still wouldn't deploy. Your input or help would be greatly appreciated!